# dynamic sort in linq

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, lambda, expression-trees

please consider this scenario:

I have a list of a class with about 50 fields.I want to have a Combobox that user can select according to what field list will sort.For example if user select "F1" list sort according to "F1".

I don't want to sort with `if-else` for every fields.I see this topic :

[Sorting a gridview when databinding a collection or list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617088/sorting-a-gridview-when-databinding-a-collection-or-list-of-objects)

but I can't use of it's answer. How I can use `Expression Tree` for this purpose?

### thanks

**Edit 1)** :

According to dear @Thom Smith answer I wrote this code:

```
 using (NorthwindModel1.NorthwindEntities2 ent = new NorthwindModel1.NorthwindEntities2())
    {
        var query = from o in ent.Orders
                    where o.OrderID < 10257
                    select o;

        query.OrderBy("CustomerID", SortDirection.Ascending);

        GridView1.DataSource = query;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

but it was not sorted. if I wrote that code in this way:

```
GridView1.DataSource = query.OrderBy(o=>o.CustomerID);
```

it being sort. where is the problem?

Comment: Have you considered Dynamic Linq? - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: thatnks but I don't wnat use third party libraries.I want to it with .Net

Comment: Fair enough, just throwing it out there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OrderBy does not do an in-place sort. It *returns* a sequence which *when evaluated* will be sorted. This is usually done lazily, meaning: until it is enumerated, it does **nothing**. Your current code simply discards this all-important return value. The fix is simple: catch the return value:

```
query = query.OrderBy("CustomerID", SortDirection.Ascending);
```

Note: similarly, applying "Where" doesn't filter the existing data: it returns a sequence that *when enumerated* is filtered. So if you were filtering you'd have the similar:

```
query = query.Where(...);
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's the method I use for this:

```
private IQueryable<T> OrderQuery<T>(IQueryable<T> query, OrderParameter orderBy)
{
    string orderMethodName = orderBy.Direction == SortDirection.Ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
    Type t = typeof(T);

    var param = Expression.Parameter(t, "shipment");
    var property = t.GetProperty(orderBy.Attribute);

    /* We can't just call OrderBy[Descending] with an Expression
     * parameter because the second type argument to OrderBy is not
     * known at compile-time.
     */
    return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(
        Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            orderMethodName,
            new Type[] { t, property.PropertyType },
            query.Expression,
            Expression.Quote(
                Expression.Lambda(
                    Expression.Property(param, property),
                    param))
        ));
}
```

`OrderParameter` is just a struct with an attribute and direction.

EDIT: Additional explanation.

This method is from my `DynamicOrderList` class, which is a list of `OrderParameter` objects. If all you need is sorting by one field, then you can simplify it a bit:

```
private IQueryable<T> OrderByDynamic<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string attribute, SortDirection direction)
{
    try
    {
        string orderMethodName = direction == SortDirection.Ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
        Type t = typeof(T);

        var param = Expression.Parameter(t);
        var property = t.GetProperty(attribute);

        return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(
            Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable),
                orderMethodName,
                new Type[] { t, property.PropertyType },
                query.Expression,
                Expression.Quote(
                    Expression.Lambda(
                        Expression.Property(param, property),
                        param))
            ));
    }
    catch (Exception) // Probably invalid input, you can catch specifics if you want
    {
        return query; // Return unsorted query
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
myQuery = myQuery.OrderByDynamic("name", SortDirection.Ascending);
```

EDIT 2:

```
public IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string attribute, SortDirection direction)
{
    return ApplyOrdering(query, attribute, direction, "OrderBy");
}

public IQueryable<T> ThenBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string attribute, SortDirection direction)
{
    return ApplyOrdering(query, attribute, direction, "ThenBy");
}

private IQueryable<T> ApplyOrdering<T>(IQueryable<T> query, string attribute, SortDirection direction, string orderMethodName)
{
    try
    {
        if (direction == SortDirection.Descending) orderMethodName += "Descending";

        Type t = typeof(T);

        var param = Expression.Parameter(t);
        var property = t.GetProperty(attribute);

        return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(
            Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable),
                orderMethodName,
                new Type[] { t, property.PropertyType },
                query.Expression,
                Expression.Quote(
                    Expression.Lambda(
                        Expression.Property(param, property),
                        param))
            ));
    }
    catch (Exception) // Probably invalid input, you can catch specifics if you want
    {
        return query; // Return unsorted query
    }
}
```

And:

```
myQuery=myQuery.OrderBy("name", SortDirection.Ascending).ThenBy("date", SortDirection.Descending);
```

Comment: thatnks How You can use this?

Comment: can you please post method that sort according multiple fields.thanks dear friend

Answer (score 2):

Here's my hot take, using `Enumerable`+Reflection instead of query:

```
list.OrderBy(x => {
                       var prop = x.GetType().GetProperty(sortFieldName);
                       return prop.GetValue(x);
                   });

if (!isSortAsc) list.Reverse();
```

Comment: Even better is to get the 'var prop = x.GetType().GetProperty(sortFieldName);' part outside the lambda expression

Comment: A shorter version for this works for older (3.5) framework:
list.OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(sortFieldName).GetValue(x));
Altough this could, and sould be optimized by putting GetType/GetProperty in an outer variable.

Answer (score -1):

Hope it will be helpful. It worked for Me to filter C# List Dynamically

```
string jtSorting = "ContactName";
DashboardModel Sup = new DashboardModel();
List<Applicant> lstSup = Sup.GetonBoard();
lstSup = lstSup.AsQueryable().SortBy(jtSorting).ToList();
```