# Sorting a GridView bound to a list of custom generic Objects

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, gridview

I'm trying to figure out how to sort a `GridView` with multiple columns (`String`, `DateTime`, `Decimal`, etc. data-types) which is bound to a generic list of custom objects.

**MyObject.vb**:

```
Public Property Id
Public Property Name
Public Property Date
Public Property Amount
```

**MyObjects.aspx.vb**:

```
gridView.DataSource = GetMyObjects()
gridView.DataBind()
```

***Note***: `GetMyObjects()` returns a `List` of `MyObject`

Basically, I need to be able to click on the column headers of the grid to sort and reverse sort, and also be able to store the sort direction in `ViewState` so the direction persists each time I click on a column header.

It seems like I probably need `MyObject` to implement `IComparable`, but I'm not sure quite how to put it all together.

Can anyone suggest a good tutorial for this, or point me in the right direction?

Comment: GridViews have an built in sorting option. This will work on one column at a time. Is that okay?

Comment: It has a built in option?  One column at a time is fine...

Comment: maybe this tutorial can help you: http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2012/06/sorting-gridview-columns-headers-aspnet.html

Comment: try "gridView.AllowSorting = true;"

Comment: In that tutorial, the gridview is bound to a dataview so that won't work for me.  My grid is bound to a generic list.

Comment: I do have the AllowSorting set to true...

Comment: well, you could add an onClickEvent to the column header. When clicked you can use something like [DataView view; view.Sort = dataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName + " ASC";]

Comment: The chosen answer here worked for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617088/sorting-a-gridview-when-databinding-a-collection-or-list-of-objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable sorting (**[AllowSorting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowsorting.aspx)**) and handle the event **[OnSorting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx)**.

***Note: The sample code uses C#, but the VB version should be similar.***

Create your **GridView**:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting">
</asp:GridView>
```

Handle **OnSorting**:

```
protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = GetObjects(e.SortDirection, e.SortExpression);
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

**GetObjects** returns a sorted `List<MyObject>`. You have to create your own sorting logic here, one alternative could be using [Dynamic Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby). If you choose that route, **GetObjects** could be defined like this: (there are better ways, but this is enough to show the theory)

```
private List<MyObject> GetObjects(SortDirection sd, string se)
{
    // Have we generated data before?
    if (SimulatedDB == null)
    {
        // Create a sample DB
        SimulatedDB = new List<MyObject>();
        var rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            var node = new MyObject();
            node.Id = i;
            node.Name = String.Format("Name {0}", i);
            node.CreationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(rnd.Next(100));
            node.Amount = (rnd.Next(1000) * rnd.NextDouble());

            SimulatedDB.Add(node);
        }
    }

    // Return sorted list
    if (sd == SortDirection.Ascending)
        return SimulatedDB.AsQueryable<MyObject>().OrderBy<MyObject>(se).ToList();
    else
        return SimulatedDB.AsQueryable<MyObject>().OrderByDescending<MyObject>(se).ToList();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I actually ended up using the answer given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617088/sorting-a-gridview-when-databinding-a-collection-or-list-of-objects  However your code does look like it may work as well, so will mark it as the answer.