# How to sort grid view data when bound with List

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am binding ASP.Net Grid View with list object. I have created Country and City Class inherited from their respective interface.

```
public interface ICountry
{
    int cmID { get; set; }
    string cmName { get; set; }        
}

public interface ICity 
{
    int ctyId { get; set; }
    string ctyName { get; set; }    
}

public class Country : ICountry
{
    public int cmID { get; set; }
    public string cmName { get; set; }     
}

 public class City : ICity
{
    public int ctyId { get; set; }
    public string ctyName { get; set; }
    public ICountry Country { get; set; }   


public List<City> GetAllCity(string SortDirection, string SortExpression)
{
   DataTable dt = FillCity()            //returns city,country in a table
   List<City> obj = new List<City>();          
   foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
   {
       City o = new City();
       o.ctyName = dr["ctyName"].ToString();
       o.Country.cmName = dr["cmName"].ToString();
       obj.Add(o);
   }

       dt.Dispose();
       return obj;          
}


    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false" PageSize="15"
AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="GRV1_PageIndexChanging"
AllowSorting="true" onsorting="GRV1_Sorting">                                    
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="ctyName ">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("ctyName")%>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Country" SortExpression="Country.cmName">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("Country.cmName")%>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns></asp:GridView>
```

I have tried to sort using Linq but failed to do so. How can I sort data in a grid view using List ?

I have tried using following but didn't work

```
            if (obj != null)
        {

            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MemorandaClosing), SortExpression);
            var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<MemorandaClosing, object>>(Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, SortExpression), typeof(object)), param);

            if (SortDirection == "ASC")
            {
                obj.AsQueryable<MemorandaClosing>().OrderBy(sortExpression);
            }
            else
            {
                obj.AsQueryable<MemorandaClosing>().OrderByDescending(sortExpression);
            };
        }
```

Comment: what is "this"? What object instance is it referring to?

Comment: Ok my bad. It is a city object instance...but why are you adding the same instance again and again to `List<City>`

Comment: Ok, post the edit, now it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys for providing me hints for the solution to my questions. Here I found the post in stack overflow which works perfect in my case.

[Building an OrderBy Lambda expression based on child entity's property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474643/building-an-orderby-lambda-expression-based-on-child-entitys-property)

Answer (score 0):

try like this in method `GetAllCity()`

this will order by CityName

```
return obj.OrderBy(x => x.ctyName).ToList();
```

Comment: what If I have to pass Sort Expression and Sort Direction to the GetAllCity() method. Like what if I need to sort using Country Name?

Answer (score 0):

In adition for what @Ganesh_Devlekar have said, you can order too by descencing using:

```
return obj.OrderByDescending(x => x.ctyName).ToList()
```

And even do some kind of filter using `Where` or something ;)

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to sort on possibly two different fields, you will need something a bit more complicated. Specifically, you would need to specify to the `GetAllCity()` method *which* field(s) you wish to sort on. Here is one possible approach (admittedly not the most elegant):

```
public List<City> GetAllCity(bool SortOnCity, bool SortOnCountry)
{
    //main code omitted for brevity

    if (SortOnCity && !SortOnCountry)
        return obj.OrderBy(x => x.ctyName).ToList();
    else if (SortOnCountry && !SortOnCity)
        return obj.OrderBy(x => x.Country.cmName).ToList();
    else if (SortOnCity && SortOnCountry)
        return obj.OrderBy(x => new {x.ctyName, x.Country.cmName}).ToList();
}
```

For my money, I would be instead passing in a lambda expression parameter which gets passed through to the `OrderBy` method, rather than having such a dirty `if...else...else`, but I think the above code demonstrates the concepts better.

To rewrite the above code passing in the SortOrder and SortExpression as variables you would do something like the following:

```
public List<City> GetAllCity<TKey>(SortDirection order, Expression<Func<City, TKey>> SortExpression)
{
    //main code omitted for brevity

    if (order == SortDirection.Ascending)
        return obj.OrderBy(SortExpression);
    else
        return obj.OrderByDescending(SortExpression);

}
```

You would then pass in a lambda expression representing the properties you want to sort on, similar to:

```
GetAllCity(SortDirection.Ascending, c => new {c.ctyName, c.Country.cmName});
```

Please note that this is just an example and may need tweaking to your particular situation.

Comment: Your last else-if condition is never going to run

Comment: You are absolutely correct sir - I will correct it. Thanks :)

Comment: Now that looks okay but I'd rather prefer to write `if (SortOnCity && SortOnCountry){}else if (SortOnCity){}else if (SortOnCountry){}`

Comment: I would never write production code like that - it is purely to demonstrate the concept.

Comment: @Katstevens Thanks for your suggestion. could you demonstrate how can I use lambda expression parameter which gets passed through to the OrderBy method.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting has to be taken care of manually. And it can be complicated based on your requirement - say if you want a 3-level sorting. Assuming you want to sort data with reference to a single field. You would need to do the following:

1. Keep track of the sort direction in ViewState
2. Handle the GridView's sorting event, and query the data appropriately from the backend.

Here is a sample snippet adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/619693/145682):

```
public SortDirection GridViewSortDirection
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
            ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;

        return (SortDirection)ViewState["sortDirection"];
    }
    set { ViewState["sortDirection"] = value; }
}

protected void gridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{           
    if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        myGridView.DataSource = GetData(e.SortExpression, SortDirection.Ascending);
        GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
    }
    else
    {
        myGridView.DataSource = GetData(e.SortExpression, SortDirection.Descending);
        GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
    };
    myGridView.DataBind();        
}
```